# Converting a String to Binary and Displaying the result

Tags: c#, binary, char

I am trying to parse individual characters in a string, convert them to binary, and then show them on a screen so that I can see the result. I have found many solutions for converting a string to binary, but I have not found any that address the problem I am seeing.
The following code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
string response = Console.ReadLine();

foreach (char c in response)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Char: " + c + "   " + Convert.ToString(c, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
}
```

Produces the following result:

```
Enter a number:
081423  
Char: 0   00110000
Char: 8   00111000
Char: 1   00110001
Char: 4   00110100
Char: 2   00110010
Char: 3   00110011
```

The question is how can I eliminate the leading "0011" characters as I only need the trailing 4 characters? Or how can I have the leading 4 characters show as "0000"? I have tried adjusting the padding value, but still get the "11" characters. Ultimately I want to accumulate the results and do not want/need the leading 4 characters.

Comment: If you really just need to display it without the leading `0011`. Why not use a `Substring()`? `Console.WriteLine("Char: " + c + "   " + Convert.ToString(c, 2).PadLeft(8, '0').Substring(4));`

Comment: Subtract `'0'`, i.e. `Convert.ToString(c - '0', 2)`

Answer (score 1):

Please, note that your current code converts *ascii code* to binary, not corresponding integer value. To have integer value, just subtract `'0'` (and pad up to length `4`):

```
Console.WriteLine($"Char: {c}   {Convert.ToString(c - '0', 2).PadLeft(4, '0')}");
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are currently trying to do is to is to convert the character, e.g. '0', and not the numerical value. The character '0' in the [ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com/) is decimal 48.

I think the thing you should do is to get the actual numerical value of the character you are after. The way to do this is to subtract the value for the character '0' from your character.

The following would give you the result you are after:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
string response = Console.ReadLine();

foreach (char c in response)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Char: " + c + "   " + Convert.ToString(c-'0', 2).PadLeft(4, '0'));
}
```

Note however that in this example, we are not validating that we indeed have a numerical value for the character, and you'd get unexpected results if we were to pass in values other that values in the `['0'-'9']` range. To make sure the values are what you are expected, you'd should to validate with

```cs
if (char.IsNumber(c))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input. I was unaware of the " - '0' " option using Convert.ToString. (I am not sure what it is doing, nor why it works when I change the padding length to 8.)
Using that and changing the padding length to 8 I am now getting the following results:

```
Console.WriteLine("Char: " + c + "   " + Convert.ToString(c - '0', 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));

Enter a date:
081423
Char: 0   00000000
Char: 8   00001000
Char: 1   00000001
Char: 4   00000100
Char: 2   00000010
Char: 3   00000011
```

BTW - it also works against alphabetic characters:

```
BlackCat
Char: B   00010010
Char: l   00111100
Char: a   00110001
Char: c   00110011
Char: k   00111011
Char: C   00010011
Char: a   00110001
Char: t   01000100
```